# jquery preload images only if no cache

Tags: jquery, image, caching, preloader

Nowadays it is very common that people add a preloader to images. It helps in rendering the website even if all images are not loaded. 
My problem here is, when preloader is called, it doesn't check for any cached image. it always load the images from the server. 
Do you have any idea to check for chached image before calling image preloader?
my preloader function is right below.

```
    $(function(){
$("#container").preloader();
});
```

it loads all the images inside the main div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to know if a image is loaded right?

```
$('#image').onload(function(){alert('Fires when image is loaded');});
```

or

```
if(document.getElementById('image').complete){alert('Image is loaded');}
```

Thats how you can check if a image is loaded or not.

Comment: i am not looking for a way to check if image is loaded or not. i'm trying to check if the same image is cached so that i can avoid calling preload function since preload function downloads the image from server everytime i visit the website.

Comment: yes, if the images are in the cache the browser will immediately load them from temp folder so you just have to 'ask' if the images have loaded

Comment: that practically is checking if the images are in cache